# Turn off time series data in a cockroachdb single-node-cluster

Tags: cockroachdb

Is there a way to turn off the the recording of time series data in a single node cluster via some start up flags?  I'm using cockroachdb version 20.1.2.

It appears this property will turn it off

```
timeseries.storage.enabled=false
```

or you can set these to 0s

```
timeseries.storage.resolution_10s.ttl=0s
timeseries.storage.resolution_30m.ttl=0s
```

I'm running cockroach in a docker container and would like to set these properties when cockroach starts but I get errors when I try to set those properties as flags.  Meaning this throws an error for invalid flag:

```
start-single-node --timeseries.storage.enabled=false --insecure
```

Is there a way to turn off timeseries data storage on startup without running queries to change cluster settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no other way.

Building and storing timeseries is a cluster-wide job and is controlled through cluster settings.

This is distinct from node-level features that can be controlled through command line flags.

You can find some details on this on the [cluster settings](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/v21.1/cluster-settings.html) page:

> In contrast to cluster-wide settings, node-level settings apply to a
> single node. They are defined by flags passed to the cockroach start
> command when starting a node and cannot be changed without stopping
> and restarting the node.